# How to update instance of Azure Application Gateway using Ansible

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-application-gateway

I am trying to automate managing some aspects of application gateway using Ansible. Some examples are adding new hosts to the backend pool, increasing instance count etc. I found examples of the azure_rm_appgateway_module here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_appgateway_module.html

However, it only has examples of creating instances of application gateway. Can someone point to some examples of how to update an existing application gateway using ansible.

Comment: Hello Subhasish, were you able to figure out how to update existing application gateway to add listeners,actually I am also struggling to find out the solution for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for quick reference on managing Azure Application Gateway using Ansible playbook,

```
- name: Create instance of Application Gateway
  azure_rm_appgateway:
    resource_group: "{{ resource_group }}"
    name: "{{ appgw_name }}"
    sku:
      name: standard_small
      tier: standard
      capacity: 2
    gateway_ip_configurations:
      - subnet:
          id: "{{ subnet.response[0].id }}"
        name: appGatewayIP
    frontend_ip_configurations:
      - public_ip_address: "{{ publicip_name }}"
        name: appGatewayFrontendIP
    frontend_ports:
      - port: 80
        name: appGatewayFrontendPort
    backend_address_pools:
      - backend_addresses:
          - ip_address: "{{ aci_1_output.response[0].properties.ipAddress.ip }}"
          - ip_address: "{{ aci_2_output.response[0].properties.ipAddress.ip }}"
        name: appGatewayBackendPool
    backend_http_settings_collection:
      - port: 80
        protocol: http
        cookie_based_affinity: enabled
        name: appGatewayBackendHttpSettings
    http_listeners:
      - frontend_ip_configuration: appGatewayFrontendIP
        frontend_port: appGatewayFrontendPort
        name: appGatewayHttpListener
    request_routing_rules:
      - rule_type: Basic
        backend_address_pool: appGatewayBackendPool
        backend_http_settings: appGatewayBackendHttpSettings
        http_listener: appGatewayHttpListener
        name: rule1
```

Ref: [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/ansible/application-gateway-configure?tabs=ansible)